# In what circumstances is a calling card dropped on kill?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Since the major update that removed gameplay-altering item set bonuses, a [calling card](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Calling_card) is now left behind "when a player is killed by another who is using a specific item set."

This sounds simple enough, but are there any specifics, i.e.,

1. is a calling card dropped only when killing using a weapon in the set, or with any weapon?
2. is a calling card dropped even if the death was feigned by a Spy using the Dead Ringer?

Or is a calling card *always* dropped?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Any weapon will do.
2. Yes. Looks like calling cards won't aid in Spy-checking after all.

I tested with the Gas Jockey item set. Kills with the Degreaser, Powerjack, or my secondary weapon which isn't part of the item set, all generated calling cards, for *every* kill. So it looks like whenever you kill or appear to have killed someone while you have the item set in your loadout, a calling card is generated. There is no catch.